# Spring Boot MVC Autoconfiguration Blocked by WebMvcConfigurationSupport

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a library JAR that taps into Spring Boot auto-configuration in order to register an interceptor for logging purposes.

My issue is that when I add the library as a dependency into a particular Spring Boot project, the interceptor is not registered.  It works for all of our other Spring Boot projects.

None of my breakpoints in the library code are hit in debug mode.

The problem Spring Boot project does have `@SpringBootApplication` and has Spring MVC via `spring-boot-starter-web`.

This class extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` seems to be preventing my interceptor from being registered:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonHttpMessageConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
{

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        om.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(om);
        return jsonConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
    }

}
```

When I delete this class, the interceptor is registered successfully.

Why is this happening and what are the approaches to fix it?

Comment: if you add the property `debug=true` to your application an autoconfiguration report will be printed out that should show you all registed autoconfigurations and why they were and were not triggered

Comment: @DarrenForsythe the InterceptorConfig class does appear in the report under the section titled "Unconditional classes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was that Spring Boot disables auto-configuration for MVC components when it sees a `@Configuration` class that extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.

The solution was to have the class not extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to include a spring-boot module in another spring-boot module. This doesn't work because the way a spring boot module is compiled and packaged means you cannot treat it as a library.

To resolve this situation you need to create a new library module and extract the code you want to use in other modules to this new module.

Comment: A library JAR containing Spring Boot annotations for auto-configuration can certainly be included as a dependency in a Spring Boot project.   This is how all of the starter projects work.

Comment: It sounds like @kernelpanic is possibly trying to use a SpringBootApplication within a SpringBootapplication but its not overly clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `implements WebMvcConfigurer` rather than `extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.